# Replace Values in pandas DataFrame with index value

Tags: python, pandas

How can I replace certain values in df, column class that have "Np" value with index values.
df

```
    class      Project 
  0  A1         Math
  1  A2         Physics
  2  Np         Music
  3  A3         Danse
  4  Np         Acting
```

I want to have this dataframe:

```
  class      Project 
  0  A1         Math
  1  A2         Physics
  2  2         Music
  3  A3         Danse
  4  4         Acting
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) to *Replace values where the condition is False*:

```
df['class'] = df['class'].where(df['class'] != 'Np', df.index.to_series())

df
  class  Project
0    A1     Math
1    A2  Physics
2     2    Music
3    A3    Danse
4     4   Acting
```

Comment: I think you actually don't event need the `to_series`

Comment: @mozway I'm getting an AttributeError if not converting to Series.

Comment: OK, funny, I had done the same without the `to_series` and it worked for me. I used `DataFrame.where` though, not `Series.where`

Comment: @mozway Ahh, interesting. Looks like they work slightly differently.

Comment: can i use replace for this problem?

Comment: @BomaAnjang It will not be the most convenient since the replacement depends on which row it's in instead of being a constant.